# performance of a plugin

Tags: performance, plugins, browser

I just want to ask, is there any explanation or is it possible that:

1. OS affecting the performance of a web browser plugin in rendering multimedia content?
2. web browser affecting the performance a web browser plugin in rendering multimedia content?